# Docusign show/hide button

Tags: docusignapi

For embedded signing , when a user starts the signing session for the first time, there is a disclaimer that can be shown to him, I know that this can be customized in the preferences.

But where do i show/hide/change the actual buttons that are shown to the user , for example there is a Review, Decline, Finish Later and Sign on paper buttons shown to him. I need to hide last two of those four buttons, How and where can i do this ?

The code i am using is from the api code walkthough for java and there is a template setup for our demo account that we are showing to the user.

Also is there a way to customize the way the button looks or can we upload a button that we already have within our site? .

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are several mechanisms for controlling things like which buttons (functions/features) are available to Signers:

- Account-level settings (controlled by the DocuSign account admin via the web console: Preferences >> Features)
- Brand-level settings (controlled by the DocuSign account admin, via customization of "Resource file(s)")
- Template-level settings (controlled by anyone with access to edit the Template's settings in the web console)
- Envelope-level settings (controlled by the sender of an envelope either via parameters set with the API call, or when manually sending an envelope via the web console)

The visibility of the **Decline** button can be controlled via the following means:

- Brand-level setting (in the Signing Resource File):  **DocuSign_DeclineAllow** boolean setting

The visibility of the **Finish Later** button can be controlled via the following means:

- Brand-level setting (in the Signing Resource File): **DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow** boolean setting

The visibility of the **Sign on Paper** button can be controlled via the following means:

- account-level setting (Preferences >> Features): **Sign on paper** checkbox
- template-level setting: **Allow recipient(s) to sign on paper.** checkbox
- envelope-level setting (via API):  **enableWetSign** boolean flag

The visibility of the **Change Signer** button can be controlled via the following means:

- account-level setting (preferences >> features): **signers can reassign envelopes** checkbox
- template-level setting: **Allow recipient(s) to change signing responsibility.**
- envelope-level setting (via API): **allowReassign** boolean flag

The following guides may be helpful to you:

- Branding [guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding):
- REST API [guide](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/):
- Administrator [guide](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide):

To hide the **Finish Later** button, you'll need to edit the Signing Resource file(s) for the Brand you plan to use with your envelopes to set the **DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow** element value to **false** -- including especially the "Captive" resource file for the "embedded signer" scenario.  See the Branding Guide I've linked to above for information about accessing/modifying the Signing Resource file(s).  Then, simply associate that Brand when sending the envelope via API by specifying the **brandId** property as part of the API request.

To hide the **Sign On Paper** button, you can use the Account-level setting, or the Template setting (if accessible/visible), or Envelope-level setting (set **enableWetSign** = **false** in the API call).

Regarding the question about button style -- while it's technically feasible for you to modify the CSS used for various elements of the DocuSign UI (if the "allow css upload" feature is enabled for your DocuSign account) -- I'd highly recommend against it. Modifying the CSS file can have very unpredicible results, and there's no easy way to "undo" your changes and get back to square one. Save yourself a lot of time and frustration, and live with the existing/default button style :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer Kim, Appreciate your help.... thanks again...

Comment: I See 5 buttons there , upload resource, upload captive resource and download master, download your resource. All of them show a different version of xml but DocuSign_DeclineAllow is present in master copy. Where should I change?

Comment: Ok, ive set the DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow element to false and uploaded both captive and the normal resource, but still no luck.

Comment: This option is only working when request is made using this admin account but its not working with another user who is not an admin for for the same account. Ive even tried using the brandID for which the changes were made in the request but its still showing Finish Later button.

Comment: Alright I guess it takes a while for the changes to be available to other users(Docusign Sender permission level) of the same account. The Finish Later button is gone now and I am also using the brand id in the envelope request.