# Remove Decline and Sign on paper buttons from docusign view

Tags: docusignapi

Is there way to hide/remove Decline and Sign on Paper buttons from docusign view when user ready to sign on docusign (USED Embedded Docusign REST API).

Please help me ASAP.

Thanks,
Srinivas Reddy. A

I have used the below link

I have changed the property of “DocuSign_DeclineAllow” to false in XML file (DocuSign_SignResources.xml) and uploaded to Docusign => Branding => Resources => Signing Resources via “Upload Resource”, Now the Decline button is disabled.

For Finish Later Button I have changed the property of “DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow” to false in XML file (DocuSign_SignResources.xml) and uploaded to Docusign => Branding => Resources => Signing Resources via “Upload Captive Resource”, but the button Finish Later is not disabled still I am seeing, also sending “brandId” property value to the API (Embedded Signing View REST API PHP).

Please help on this ASAP

Comment: See this (duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074868/docusign-show-hide-button/19085000.

Comment: Yes as Kim has mentioned this is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074868/docusign-show-hide-button/19085000)

Comment: I have tried to hide decline button, but I didn't get. Where I need to change. Please provide detailed steps or screen shots. I am using PHP Rest API. Please help me on this. thanks in advance. Very Urgent

Comment: I have changed the property of “DocuSign_DeclineAllow” to false in XML file (DocuSign_SignResources.xml) and uploaded to Docusign => Branding => Resources => Signing Resources via “Upload Resource”, Now the Decline button is disabled.

Comment: For Finish Later Button I have changed the property of “DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow” to false in XML file (DocuSign_SignResources.xml) and uploaded to Docusign => Branding => Resources => Signing Resources via “Upload Captive Resource”, but the button Finish Later is not disabled still I am seeing, also sending “brandId” property value to the API (Embedded Signing View REST API PHP).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not be looking to remove user's ability to decline a contract.  Users should be engaging in any legally binding transaction only out of free will.