# DocuSign option for decline to sign missing

Tags: docusignapi

I am having an issue where the option to "decline" signing is no longer under the "other actions" button when you are assigned a document to sign.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the **Decline** button can be controlled via the following means:

- Brand-level setting (in the Signing Resource File): DocuSign_DeclineAllow boolean setting

See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085000/1219543) for more information