# Docusign settings through master resource file not working

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to disable declining, finishing later, downloading and printing for the user when they are signing a document. I'm trying to do it through the master resource file, as I didn't see those options in the settings interface.

The settings do not take effect after uploading the file, however. The following is the master resource file download after setting those items to false.

```
<root>
  <language twoletterisoname="en">
    <data name="DocuSign_DeclineAllow">false</data>
    <data name="DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow">false</data>
    <data name="DocuSign_SigningAllowDownload">false</data>
    <data name="DocuSign_SigningAllowPrint">false</data>
  </language>
</root>
```

Is there something wrong in how they are set? I also tried removing the "en" (and leaving just "") but no difference. We are using standard signing, not captive. We we only have one brand. We are generating a new envelope every submission. Logging out and back in does not resolve the issue either.

Not sure if this makes a difference, but the envelope is being submitted from Salesforce.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085000/1219543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. We only had one brand, but it wasn't being selected by default. The brand ID had to be explicitly set when generating the envelope through the API. Once that was done the settings started working.

Answer (score 1):

When uploading the xml file for signing, you should not upload everyhting from master. Just upload which is the delta change, try uploading xml with only below changes

```
<root>
 <language twoletterisoname="">
  <data name="DocuSign_DeclineAllow">false</data>
  <data name="DocuSign_FinishLaterAllow">false</data>
  <data name="DocuSign_SigningAllowDownload">false</data>
  <data name="DocuSign_SigningAllowPrint">false</data>
 </language>
</root>
```

Save above in an xml and then upload this delta and then try it. Hope this will fix it. I tried and it works for me.