# How to remove the Continue button and Other Actions Drop down from the signing window in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

How to remove the Continue button and Other Actions Drop down from the signing window headlined "Please review the documents below." in case of Embedded signing. I need to directly move to the page where signer can draw signatures and finish the process.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to completely remove the Other Actions menu. However you can remove some of the options.

There are various ways to accomplish this

- Account-level settings
- Brand-level settings
- Template-level settings
- Envelope-level settings

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085000/1219543) for more information.