# DocuSign - not able to disable "decline to sign"

Tags: docusignapi

I need to disable the "Decline to Sign" option in the other actions drop down to restrict the user to decline. Is there any option in DocuSign to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-signing-resource-file-v2-0 might help.

```
DocuSign_DeclineAllow
```

is the field name

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible to remove the "Decline" button at the envelope level or recipient level. But you can control the visibility of the **Decline** button via the Brand-level setting `DocuSign_DeclineAllow` (set to a boolean value) in the Signing Resource File.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074868/docusign-show-hide-button/19085000#19085000) for more information.

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you please mark this answer as “accepted” (so that it’ll be more discoverable for others in the future)? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for keep answering questions here Kim, really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the signer can simply close the signing ceremony's browser tab...so they can always, effectively, "decline to sign."

The usual way to handle this is to not allow the user to proceed until after they've signed. Hiding the `Decline to Sign` button is security through obscurity (which is no security at all).